# Convergence in distribution and in probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

I am trying to show that if $X_n \rightarrow X$ in distribution there exist $Y_n \sim X_n$ and $Y \sim X$ such that $Y_n \rightarrow Y$ in probability.

I take $U \sim \mathcal{U}([0,1])$ and define $Y_n = F_{X_n}^{-1}(U)$ and $Y = F_{X}^{-1}(U)$ but I don't see how to prove the convergence in probability.

Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: It's Skorokhod's representation theorem. You may find it in many books on probability theory.

Comment: Thank you very much!